# Bluetooth stopped working in Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth

I'm seeing a strange issue of **No Bluetooth devices not being discovered** after a restart.

I upgraded my machine from 16.04 to 18.04 and I was just happy that bluetooth is working with the latest.

PS:
I have also tried multiple solutions like

1. Restarting the machine
2. Restarting bluetooh through commandline
3. Also copy pased and ran a few commands posted in the few answers mentioned already

[Here is the screenshot of bluetooth searching for devices forever](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9xiq.png)

`rfkill list                                                        16:32:24
    0: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
    1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
    2: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no`

Edit:

`hciconfig --all
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 08:ED:B9:92:B8:6E  ACL MTU: 1021:8  SCO MTU: 64:1
    UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN INQUIRY 
    RX bytes:1868 acl:0 sco:0 events:137 errors:0
    TX bytes:5788 acl:0 sco:0 commands:131 errors:0
    Features: 0xff 0xfe 0xcf 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
    Name: 'sujeet-pc'
    Class: 0x1c010c
    Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing, Object Transfer
    Device Class: Computer, Laptop
    HCI Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Revision: 0x0
    LMP Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Subversion: 0x210b
    Manufacturer: Broadcom Corporation (15)`

**Edit 2:**
`brcm dmesg | grep Blue`
`[   34.529720] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   34.529738] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   34.529741] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   34.529743] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   34.529746] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   39.262414] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[   39.263363] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[   39.279373] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A
[   39.279380] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.011) build 0000
[   39.475850] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM.hcd not found
[   50.855282] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   50.855284] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   50.855288] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   53.760056] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[  170.970381] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[  170.970392] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[  170.970399] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[ 1930.483146] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[ 1930.484135] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[ 1930.500145] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A
[ 1930.500149] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.011) build 0000
[ 1930.500168] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM.hcd not found
[ 1932.533242] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout`

also, Contents of the exisistig brcm folder

`➜  brcm ls -la
total 16580
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Aug  1 14:42 .
drwxr-xr-x 85 root root   36864 Aug  1 14:42 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  269595 Mar 30  2017 bcm4329-fullmac-4.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   96224 Mar 30  2017 bcm43xx-0.fw
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     180 Mar 30  2017 bcm43xx_hdr-0.fw
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  397312 Mar 30  2017 brcmfmac43143.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  385067 Nov 17  2017 brcmfmac43143-sdio.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  348160 Mar 30  2017 brcmfmac43236b.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  455745 Mar 30  2017 brcmfmac43241b0-sdio.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  403855 Mar 30  2017 brcmfmac43241b4-sdio.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  408682 Mar 30  2017 brcmfmac43241b5-sdio.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  479232 Mar 30  2017 brcmfmac43242a.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  253748 Mar 30  2017 brcmfmac4329-sdio.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  222126 Mar 30  2017 brcmfmac4330-sdio.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  402210 Jul 12 20:24 brcmfmac43340-sdio.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  451566 Mar 30  2017 brcmfmac4334-sdio.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  569291 Mar 30  2017 brcmfmac4335-sdio.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  219557 Jul 12 20:24 brcmfmac43362-sdio.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  562183 Jul 12 18:00 brcmfmac4339-sdio.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  382455 Apr 25  2018 brcmfmac43430a0-sdio.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  369577 Jul 12 20:24 brcmfmac43430-sdio.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  488193 Mar 30  2017 brcmfmac43455-sdio.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  623304 Nov 17  2017 brcmfmac4350c2-pcie.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  626140 Mar 30  2017 brcmfmac4350-pcie.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  626589 Jul 12 20:24 brcmfmac4354-sdio.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  557056 Mar 30  2017 brcmfmac43569.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  661999 Jul 12 20:24 brcmfmac4356-pcie.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  526383 Nov 17  2017 brcmfmac4356-sdio.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  550333 Mar 30  2017 brcmfmac43570-pcie.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  633817 Jul 12 18:00 brcmfmac4358-pcie.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  595472 Nov 17  2017 brcmfmac43602-pcie.ap.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  635449 Nov 17  2017 brcmfmac43602-pcie.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  989401 Jul 12 20:24 brcmfmac4366b-pcie.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1120971 Jul 12 18:12 brcmfmac4366c-pcie.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  623448 Mar 30  2017 brcmfmac4371-pcie.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  479232 Apr 25  2018 brcmfmac4373.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  457994 Apr 25  2018 brcmfmac4373-sdio.bin`

**Edit 3:lsusb | grep -i blue**
`lsusb | grep -i blue

Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:21d7 Broadcom Corp. BCM43142 Bluetooth 4.0`

**Edit 4: sudo systemctl status bluetooth**

```
sudo systemctl status bluetooth 

 bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2019-08-04 22:09:10 IST; 2s ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 9555 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─9555 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Aug 04 22:09:10 sujeet-pc systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Aug 04 22:09:10 sujeet-pc bluetoothd[9555]: Bluetooth daemon 5.50
Aug 04 22:09:10 sujeet-pc systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Aug 04 22:09:10 sujeet-pc bluetoothd[9555]: Starting SDP server
Aug 04 22:09:10 sujeet-pc bluetoothd[9555]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
```

Comment: ` hciconfig --all` Please edit your question for output.

Comment: Done, please revisit the question

Comment: It may be, but the solution is not always straight forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I fixed my bluettoh problem.
It took only 5 mins to do with attention.

here is the link 
https://medium.com/@sujeetb/how-i-fixed-my-bluetooth-issue-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts-805c865fa87

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `linux-firmware` is installed.

Control with `dmesg | grep Blue` that your bluetooth find his firmware. Should similiar look like mine `Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A`
 
If the firmware is missing, you can download it from [git](https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/tree/master/brcm)

and move it in the folder `/lib/firmware/brcm/`

Comment: I have updated the answer again, can you please look into it and suggest a fix.
Also i see so many BCM43142A0X-XXXX-XXXX.hcd files in the git URL shared by you

Comment: I forgot, please show `lsusb | grep -i blue`

Comment: I kind of messed up the entire thing :(

I kind of disabled and enabled broadcom drivers and bluetooth doesnt even turn ON now.

here are images https://imgur.com/a/WM12y8m

Comment: also added output of `lsusb | grep -i blue` in edit 3 of the quesion.